# integrating a tricky function $\int\sec^3x\ln (\arctan e^x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integrate the flowing $$\int\sec^3x\ln (\arctan e^x)dx$$ i tried u substitution using $u=e^x$ and $ \arctan e^x=u$ and also $\sec^3x=u$, but i found nothing. What would you suggest?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: @Maryam yes i did

Comment: I don't think this has an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: @Chappers .. but the function is continous so it has one ..

Comment: It has an antiderivative. But not an antiderivative composed of a finite combination of elementary functions, which is what an elementary antiderivative is. See the links in @Lucian's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What would you suggest ?*

I would suggest acquainting yourself with [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).